# Sharepoint Hosted App Model Controls not displaying

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, office365, office365-apps

While working on customizing the Share-point Site we have used Share-point Hosted App Model. There is an issue that I am currently facing on when using App Model.

Following are the steps I have done.

1. Created an Share-point Hosted App Model using Visual Studio.
2. When the app is created there are in-built files named as App.js and default.aspx
3. The code in App.js file will get the current context and display the current login person name inside a p tag present in default.aspx
4. At this point I am getting the username and I can see it inside the p tag.
5. In the default.aspx I have added controls such as text-area, button, text-box and build was succeeded and I deployed the solution.
6. Now in my share-point site, I created a new page and added the App-part, but is not displaying in my page. Its showing as

[image]

Code in

**AppManifest file**

```
<AppPrincipal>
<Internal/>
</AppPrincipal>
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="false">
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="Manage" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

**Default.aspx**

```
 <%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Language="C#" %>

    <%@ Register TagPrefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
    <%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
    <%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

    <%-- The markup and script in the following Content element will be placed in the <head> of the page --%>
    <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.js" runat="server" OnDemand="true" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
        <meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />

        <!-- Add your CSS styles to the following file -->
        <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Content/App.css" />

        <!-- Add your JavaScript to the following file -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/App.js"></script>
    </asp:Content>

    <%-- The markup in the following Content element will be placed in the TitleArea of the page --%>
    <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
        Page Title
    </asp:Content>

    <%-- The markup and script in the following Content element will be placed in the <body> of the page --%>
    <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">

        <div>
            <p id="message">
                <!-- The following content will be replaced with the user name when you run the app - see App.js -->
                initializing...
            </p>
    <input type="text" id="txtApprove" name="txtApprove"/>
    <input type="button" value="Approve" id="btnApprove" name="btnApprove"/>
        </div>

    </asp:Content>
```

**App.js**

```
'use strict';

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(initializePage, "sp.js");

function initializePage()
{
    var context = new SP.ClientContext("/sites/sitename");
    var user = context.get_web().get_currentUser();
    var oListItem;
    // This code runs when the DOM is ready and creates a context object which is needed to use the SharePoint object model
    $(document).ready(function () {        
        getUserName();
        UpdateWFStatusColumn(58);
    });

    // This function prepares, loads, and then executes a SharePoint query to get the current users information
    function getUserName() {
        context.load(user);
        context.executeQueryAsync(onGetUserNameSuccess, onGetUserNameFail);
    }

    // This function is executed if the above call is successful
    // It replaces the contents of the 'message' element with the user name
    function onGetUserNameSuccess() {
        $('#message').text('Hello ' + user.get_title());
    }

    // This function is executed if the above call fails
    function onGetUserNameFail(sender, args) {
        alert('Failed to get user name. Error:' + args.get_message());
    }

    function UpdateWFStatusColumn(itemId) {
        var web = context.get_web();
        var oList = web.get_lists().getByTitle('EmpList');
        oListItem = oList.getItemById(itemId);
        oListItem.set_item('ApprovalStages', 'Approval');
        oListItem.update();
        context.load(oListItem);
        context.executeQueryAsync(
            function (sender, args) {
                alert("Workflow started");
            },
            function (sender, args) {
                alert("Failed to load subscription.");
                alert("Error: " + args.get_message() + "\n" + args.get_stackTrace());
            }
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: You are adding app-part.. Have you created Client Webpart ?

Comment: Yes. I have created app Model and but not Client Webpart